# Ionic 3 Failed to restore "com.attendee.barcodegenerator" in config.xml

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In the Ionic project, I removed the attachment that I had previously attached. But when I build the project I get an error. I mentioned the fault below. I could not find a solution. I delete the necessary places in Config.xml, but this line is added again when it is rebuilt. I'm glad you found a solution to the problem. Thank you

```js
Discovered plugin "com.attendee.barcodegenerator" in config.xml. Adding it to the project

Failed to restore plugin "com.attendee.barcodegenerator" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin com.attendee.barcodegenerator@~0.0.4 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: com.attendee.barcodegenerator@~0.0.4

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/CAN/.npm/_logs/2017-10-31T14_51_47_381Z-debug.log
```

```js
<plugin name="com.attendee.barcodegenerator" spec="~0.0.4" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-barcode-generator --save
```

Comment: "Error: Plugin "cordova-barcode-generator" is not present in the project. See `cordova plugin list`. " i am getting this result

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: When I write your command, it gives me the result of the comment I just wrote

Comment: Yes type `cordova plugin list` and show the result to us.

Comment: He just gives me a line about it. com.attendee.barcodegenerator 0.0.4 "barcode-generator"

Comment: OK. Just go to the `Plugins` folder and delete it manually.Do the same for the `config.xml` too if it also has it. Only the `barcode-generator` folder.

Comment: and when I built it I ran into a mistake like this.

 "Discovered plugin" com.attendee.barcodegenerator "in config.xml. Adding it to the project

Failed to restore plugin "com.attendee.barcodegenerator" from config.xml. You might need to try it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.attendee.barcodegenerator "

Comment: Did you follow the above steps which I told?

Comment: Yes I told your above steps

Comment: Can you install that plugin again? `cordova plugin add cordova-barcode-generator --save`

Comment: I tried all the methods you said, but I did not get a result. I carried the project to a clean application and got a clean project Thank you for your suggestions :)